# What is good $t$-adic like topology on $\mathbb{C}(t)$?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, gn.general-topology, p-adic-analysis

Each function $f\in\mathbb{C}(t)$ can be rewritten in the form $f = a_{k}t^{k}+\ldots+a_0+a_1t+\ldots$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and it is possible to define the topology with the open prebase at zero

$V_{n,v,\varepsilon} = \{f=a_kt^k+\ldots+a_0+a_1t+\ldots\in \mathbb{C}(t)| \sum_{k\leq m<n}|m|^v|a_m|<\varepsilon\}$

> Question. Is this Lindelöf topology?

Comment: I don't think there's a natural locally compact topology on $\mathbb{C}(t)$: the fields admitting such a thing are called [local fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_field) and are completely classified (this might be possible to fix by asking for a weaker compatibility of the topology with the field structure, but I'm personally .skeptical)

Comment: Thank you. What about $\sigma$ compact topology?

Comment: Each one of your prebasic open sets is $t$-adically open (the set contains the open disk of radius $p^{-n}$ around each of its points). But for every $n$, the $t$-adic disk of radius $p^{-n}$ centered at $0$ contains $V_{n+1,n+2,\{1\}}$. So it seems to me that this topology is the same as the $t$-adic topology.

Comment: Ok, I edited the definition

Comment: This seems vaguely like dealing with the [box topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology) instead of the product topology, and probably runs into similar issues.

Comment: Also I think that in my example product $1/(1+t)^5\times *$ isn't continious map. So better to state that $\sum_{i=n}^{-\infty}e^i|b_i|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: What if we consider the inverse limit of topological rings $\mathbf{C}[t]/t^n$ each with the Euclidean topology? This gives a mixture of the $t$-adic and Euclidean topologies on $\mathbf{C}[[t]]$. I didn't check, but it may be that this topology does not extend to a ring topology $\mathbf{C}((t))$.

Comment: Your topology looks like $V_{n,v,\varepsilon}\cap\mathbb{C}[[t]]$ open prebase topology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\|f\|_{n, m} = \sum_{i<n}(|i|^m+10)|a_i|$ denote a family of seminorms on $\mathbb{C}(t)$. Note that for any $\{(n_v, m_v)\}_{v\text{ in finite subset of }\mathbb{N}}$ there is a seminorm $\|.\|_{n,m}$ such that $\|f\|_{n, m}\geq\sup_v\|f\|_{n_v, m_v}$. Also these seminorms define the same topology as stated in the problem. Resulting topological space is separabel so for some countable set of $F_i\in\mathbb{C}(t)$ this set is dense. Let $\{U_{\lambda}\}$ be some open cover of this topological space. For each $F_i$ and $(n, m)$ define $\varepsilon_{i, n, m}$ as supremum of $\varepsilon >0$ such that the $\varepsilon$ ball around $F_i$ in $\|.\|_{n, m}$ lies inside of $U_{\lambda}$ for some $\lambda$ and let $\{\|f\|_{n, m}<\varepsilon_{i, n, m}/2\}\subset U_{\lambda_{i, n, m}}$ in result $\cup_{i, n, m}U_{\lambda_{i, n, m}}$ is countable open subcover.